# How do I cast a child collection of IEnumerable<T> to EntityCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using EF, so my Child collections are of type EntityCollection < T >. If property "Children" is EntityCollection < T > How do I convert the query result IEnumerable < T > to EntityCollection < T >?

Thanks

```
 var list = element.Elements(ns + "Parent")
        .Select(parsedXml => 
                        Children = parsedXml.Elements(ns + "Child")
                        .Select(child => new Child { 
                                                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(child.Attribute("id").Value)
                                                   })
                        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using LINQ you can do this with the same model by creating an extension method:

```
public static EntityCollection<T> ToEntityCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) 
{
    var col = new EntityCollection<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        col.Add(item);
    }
    return col;
}
```

Then use this in your original LINQ statement by adding `.ToEntityCollection()` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct casting available. You will need to loop through the collection and add to the new entity collection.

```
var eCollection = new EntityCollection<T>();    
foreach (var child in list)
{
    eCollection.Add(child );
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient because it loops through the list twice.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I edited my post; I had this before in place of the foreach on ienumerable list `'list.ToList().ForEach(a => eCollection.Add(a));`